# Shiny widgets in DT Table

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, shiny, dt

I'm trying to include shiny widgets such as textInput, selectInput (single), sliderInput, and selectInput (multiple) in the rows of a DT table.  When the widgets are directly on the page, they display correctly, however, when they are put in the table, some of them do not display correctly.

The textInput is fine and the selectInput (single) is mostly fine save for some css differences, but the selectInput (multiple) isn't displaying correctly and the sliderInput definitely isn't displaying correctly.  It seems the widgets that rely on javascript are the ones that have issues.  Is there a way to make these widgets work correctly in the DT table?

Here is my reproducible example.  I used the raw HTML for the widgets when putting them in the table, but I took that directly from the HTML generated by the shiny functions for each widget.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h3("This is how I want the widgets to look in the DT table."),
  fluidRow(column(3, textInput(inputId = "text",
                               label = "TEXT")),
           column(3, selectInput(inputId = "single_select",
                                 label = "SINGLE SELECT",
                                 choices = c("", "A", "B", "C"))),
           column(3, sliderInput(inputId = "slider",
                                 label = "SLIDER",
                                 min = 0,
                                 max = 10,
                                 value = c(0, 10))),
           column(3, selectizeInput(inputId = "multiple_select",
                                    label = "MULTIPLE SELECT",
                                    choices = c("", "A", "B", "C"),
                                    multiple = TRUE))),
  h3("This is how they actually appear in a DT table."),
  fluidRow(DTOutput(outputId = "table"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderDT({
    data <- data.frame(ROW = 1:5,
                       TEXT = '<input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>',
                       SINGLE_SELECT = '<select id="single_select" style="width: 100%;">
                                          <option value="" selected></option>
                                          <option value="A">A</option>
                                          <option value="B">B</option>
                                          <option value="C">C</option>
                                        </select>',
                       SLIDER = '<input class="js-range-slider" id="slider" data-type="double" data-min="0" data-max="10" data-from="0" data-to="10" data-step="1" data-grid="true" data-grid-num="10" data-grid-snap="false" data-prettify-separator="," data-prettify-enabled="true" data-keyboard="true" data-drag-interval="true" data-data-type="number"/>',
                       MULTIPLE_SELECT = '<select id="multiple_select" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                            <option value="B">B</option>
                                            <option value="C">C</option>
                                          </select>',
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    datatable(data = data,
              selection = "none",
              escape = FALSE,
              rownames = FALSE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Sliders

For the sliders, you have to start with a text input:

```
SLIDER = '<input type="text" id="s" name="slider" value="" />'
```

and then turn it into a slider with JavaScript:

```
js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  $('#s').ionRangeSlider({",
  "    type: 'double',",
  "    grid: true,",
  "    grid_num: 10,",
  "    min: 0,",
  "    max: 20,",
  "    from: 5,",
  "    to: 15",
  "  });",
  "}"
)
```

See [ionRangeSlider](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider) for the options.

You can pass the JavaScript code with the `initComplete` option:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderDT({
    data <- data.frame(ROW = 1:5,
                       TEXT = '<input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>',
                       SINGLE_SELECT = '<select id="single_select" style="width: 100%;">
                       <option value="" selected></option>
                       <option value="A">A</option>
                       <option value="B">B</option>
                       <option value="C">C</option>
                       </select>',
                       SLIDER = '<input type="text" id="s" name="slider" value="" />',
                       MULTIPLE_SELECT = '<select id="multiple_select" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                       <option value=""></option>
                       <option value="A">A</option>
                       <option value="B">B</option>
                       <option value="C">C</option>
                       </select>',
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    datatable(data = data,
              selection = "none",
              escape = FALSE,
              rownames = FALSE, 
              options = 
                list(
                  initComplete = JS(js)
                ))
  })

}
```

Then you get the slider for the first row only:

[image]

That's because the five text inputs have the same id. You have to set a different id for the five text inputs:

```
SLIDER = sapply(1:5, function(i) {
  sprintf('<input type="text" id="Slider%d" name="slider" value="" />', i)
}),
```

Then use this JavaScript code to turn them into sliders:

```
js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  $('[id^=Slider]').ionRangeSlider({",
  "    type: 'double',",
  "    grid: true,",
  "    grid_num: 10,",
  "    min: 0,",
  "    max: 20,",
  "    from: 5,",
  "    to: 15",
  "  });",
  "}"
)
```

[image]

To set the initial values of `from` and `to`, it's better to give them in the `value` argument of the input text like this:

```
SLIDER = sapply(1:5, function(i) {
  sprintf('<input type="text" id="Slider%d" name="slider" value="5;15" />', i)
})

js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  $('[id^=Slider]').ionRangeSlider({",
  "    type: 'double',",
  "    grid: true,",
  "    grid_num: 10,",
  "    min: 0,",
  "    max: 20",
  "  });",
  "}"
)
```

## Multiple selects

To get the desired display of a multiple select, you have to call `selectize()`:

```
MULTIPLE_SELECT = '<select id="mselect" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                       <option value=""></option>
                       <option value="A">A</option>
                       <option value="B">B</option>
                       <option value="C">C</option>
                    </select>'
js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  $('[id^=Slider]').ionRangeSlider({",
  "    type: 'double',",
  "    grid: true,",
  "    grid_num: 10,",
  "    min: 0,",
  "    max: 20",
  "  });",
  "  $('#mselect').selectize()",
  "}"
)
```

Similarly, this applies to the first multiple select only. Use individual id's to apply to the five ones.

## Binding

Finally, you have to bind the inputs to get their value available in Shiny:

```
datatable(data = data,
          selection = "none",
          escape = FALSE,
          rownames = FALSE, 
          options = 
            list(
              initComplete = JS(js),
              preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
              drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
            )
)
```

Now you can get the values in `input$Slider1`, `input$Slider2`, ..., and `input$mselect`. Note that `input$Slider[1/2/3/4/5]` returns the values of the slider in this format: `"3;15"`.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I needed.  I think I'm going to want to have a date range input as well but I think I can figure out how to do that based on how you did these.

Comment: @mosk915 See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633326/dateinput-not-working-on-dt-in-shiny/55058263#55058263) for the date input.

Comment: I have one follow up question if you don't mind.  How hard would it be to make the slider appear in a dropdown, similar to the way it appears in a column filter for a numeric column where you see a text box and then the slider drops down below the box when you click in it?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent how do you do a single select? I think I asked a similar question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269142/how-to-have-html-select-input-widget-in-dt-datatable-rows-r

Comment: This last part **Binding** was exactly what I was looking for. It transfers very well to storing buttons in a Data Table.

Comment: Super helpful answer! Interested though in how you would edit the Single Select if you needed the choices to be dynamic and looked up from a table based on some other input.