# How to have html select input widget in DT datatable rows? R

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have the following shiny app.

```
# GLOBAL ----
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

SELECT = '<select year="" id="year-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>'



test_cars <- data.frame("Num" = c(1:5),
                        "Make" = c("Toyota","","","",""),
                        "Model" = c("Camry","","","",""))

test_cars$Year <- SELECT

# UI ----
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = 'Cars Editor',
  tabPanel("Cars Entry",DTOutput("table1")),
  tabPanel("About")
)

# SERVER ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(test_cars %>% select(!Num), editable = "all", escape = FALSE, extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons =
                  list('copy', 'print', list(
                    extend = 'collection',
                    buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                    text = 'Download'
                  ))

              )
    )
  })

}
# Run app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this gives me the following: My goal is for the users to select an input from the "Year" column and have it be saved to the data.

[image]

But when I click download, I get all the options that were in the html select input and not the user's selection. Any thoughts on how I should approach this?

[image]

Comment: Check this answer, maybe will help you get where you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685412/how-to-add-selectinput-to-each-row-of-a-datatable-in-r-shiny-and-then-read-it

Comment: You can't with the download button. You have to use an "ordinary" download.

Comment: What would be the input that goes back into my ordinary action button?

Comment: Also if something else than DT will work check package: rhandsontable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with some custom exporting options.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

SELECT = '<select year="" id="year-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>'



test_cars <- data.frame("Num" = c(1:5),
                        "Make" = c("Toyota","","","",""),
                        "Model" = c("Camry","","","",""))

test_cars$Year <- SELECT

# UI ----
ui <- navbarPage(
    title = 'Cars Editor',
    tabPanel("Cars Entry",DTOutput("table1")),
    tabPanel("About")
)

# SERVER ----
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table1 <- renderDT({
        datatable(test_cars %>% select(!Num), editable = "all", escape = FALSE, extensions = 'Buttons',
                  options = list(
                      dom = 'Bfrtip',
                      buttons =
                          list('copy', 'print', list(
                              extend = 'collection',
                              text = 'Download',
                              buttons = list('csv', 'excel', list(
                                  extend = "pdf",
                                  exportOptions = list(
                                      format = list(
                                          body = JS(
                                            "
                                              function(data, row, col, node) {
                                                  return $(node).has('select').length ?
                                                    $(node).find(':selected').text(): data
                                              }
                                            "
                                          )
                                      )
                                  )
                              ))
                          ))
                      
                  )
        )
    })
    
}

# Run app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

1. This post uses the `pdf` exporting option as example, you can do the same for other exporting options.
2. When it comes to export the data, we add a custom JS function to tell datatable how to render the `body`.
3. It checks if the cell has `select` tag inside, if so, get the selected value from the dropdown, otherwise return raw value.

Read [`buttons.exportData`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()) for details.

[image]

[image]