# Shiny DT datatable using selectInput with multiple = TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In my Shiny app, I want to include a selectInput in a DT datatable and allow selection of multiple options. This renders fine with `multiple = F`, but with `multiple = T`, the selection doesn't display or work properly. Please see example below. When "Multiple" is unselected, the selectInput renders fine in the table, but when it is selected, the selectInput is not rendered properly. Any suggestions?

**Update**: I modified the code to include a selectInput by itself with `multiple = TRUE` to show what I expect it to look like in the table. Specifically, in the table, there is no field above the dropdown with the selections displayed and I am unable to select multiple choices. Also see screenshot.
[image]

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    checkboxInput(inputId = "multiple", label = "Multiple", value = F),
    selectInput(inputId = "expected", label = "Expected", choices = letters, multiple = T),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      if(is.null(input$multiple)) return()
      DT::datatable(
        data = data.frame(
          Col1 = c(
            as.character(selectInput(
              inputId = "id1", 
              label = NULL, 
              choices = letters, 
              multiple = input$multiple
            ))
          )
        ),
        escape = F,
        selection = "none"
      )
    })
  }
)
```

**Update 2**:
Thanks to @Jamie for a great solution. I was able to modify that solution when I need multiple selectInputs in my table and want the same desired format. See below:

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

SelectizeIDs <- function(ids) {
  myStrings <- as.character(sapply(ids, function(id) {
    paste0("  $('#", id, "').selectize();")
  }))
  c(
    "function(settings){",
      myStrings,
    "}"
  )
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    checkboxInput(inputId = "multiple", label = "Multiple", value = F),
    selectInput(inputId = "expected", label = "Expected", choices = letters, multiple = T),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        data = data.frame(
          Col1 = c(
            as.character(selectInput(
              inputId = "id1",
              label = NULL,
              choices = letters,
              multiple = input$multiple
            )),
            as.character(selectInput(
              inputId = "id2",
              label = NULL,
              choices = letters,
              multiple = input$multiple
            ))
          )
        ),
        escape = F,
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          ordering = F,
          initComplete = JS(SelectizeIDs(c("id1", "id2"))),
          preDrawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
          drawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')
        )
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I ran this and didn't see a problem. With multiple unticked, the selection box opened to show all values. When it was ticked it only showed the first four, but I was able to scroll down and select multiple options. What is your expectation?

Comment: Works as expected for me too

Comment: @stomper I updated my code to include a selectInput by itself with multiple = T which is how I expect it to look in the table. Also included screenshot

Comment: @HubertL please see update. Does your app not look like my screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option where I leaned heavily from this question.

[SelectizeInput inside DT::datatable only works as html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091821/selectizeinput-inside-dtdatatable-only-works-as-html)

Which leans on this question. [Shiny widgets in DT Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034483/shiny-widgets-in-dt-table/55041373#55041373)

Since your `data` data.frame has the appropriate html already set up. You need to make sure that selectize is added to the id in this case `id1`. From inspecting element on your expected vs actual input, it looks like all the selectize JS is being excluded

```
js <- c(
  "function(settings){",
  "  $('#id1').selectize()",
  "}"
)
```

Then in the options initialize the js function above and and bind the inputs.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    checkboxInput(inputId = "multiple", label = "Multiple", value = F),
    selectInput(inputId = "expected", label = "Expected", choices = letters, multiple = T),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      # if(is.null(input$multiple)) return()
      DT::datatable(
        data = data.frame(
          Col1 = c(
            as.character(selectInput(
              inputId = "id1",
              label = NULL,
              choices = letters,
              multiple = input$multiple
            ))
          )
        ),
        escape = F,
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          initComplete = JS(js),
          preDrawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
          drawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')
        )
      )
    })
  }
)
```

[image: output]

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you. One minor tweak is to set `ordering = F` in the options list. I clicked on the column header (accidentally) which sorted the table and noticed that it reverted back to the original (not desired) format. 
And one follow up question: how would I extend the "js" code snippet if I have multiple selectInputs in my table?

Comment: See update 2. I was able to extend your js snippet to selectize multiple selectInput ids. Thanks again.

Comment: Could also consider `selectInputMultiple` in from the `DTEdit` package