# Vertically center selectInput in Shiny DT datatable when selectize javascript is applied

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I have a selectInput in a Shiny DT datatable. I needed to apply custom javascript to selectize the selectInput due to a formatting issue when using `multiple = T` (see other post: [Shiny DT datatable using selectInput with multiple = TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551824/shiny-dt-datatable-using-selectinput-with-multiple-true)). (As a side note, I also noticed that I must have a selectInput outside the datatable for the javascript to work, hence the hidden "dummy" selectInput; I would love to know why this is). When I do this, I am unable to vertically center the selectInput on its row. In the code below, if the `initComplete` line is commented out, the selectInput is vertically centered (due to the `margin-bottom: 0` css), but the correct appearance and multiple selections are lost. I would appreciate help getting the selectInput vertically centered while keeping the correct formatting. Note that I've left out some additional javascript for binding/unbinding inputs to keep the code minimal.

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

# Function to selectize one or more input ids
SelectizeIDs <- function(ids) {
  myStrings <- as.character(sapply(ids, function(id) {
    paste0("  $('#", id, "').selectize();")
  }))
  c(
    "function(settings){",
    myStrings,
    "}"
  )
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("td .form-group {margin-bottom: 0;}"))),
    # Dummy selectInput is needed for SelectizeIDs() to work, not sure why
    div(style = "display: none;", selectInput(inputId = "dummy", label = NULL, choices = 1:2)),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        data = data.frame(
          Col1 = as.character(selectInput(
            inputId = "id1",
            label = NULL,
            choices = letters,
            multiple = T
          ))
        ),
        escape = F,
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          initComplete = JS(SelectizeIDs("id1"))
        )
      ) 
    })
  }
)
```

Here is a screenshot using the code above showing the selectInput properly formatted but not vertically centered:
[image]

Here is a screenshot using the code above but commenting out the `initComplete` line, showing the selectInput improperly formatted but vertically centered:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the dummy selectize input, the **selectize.js** library is not included.

The CSS:

```r
    tags$head(tags$style(
      HTML("td .form-group {margin-bottom: 0;} td .selectize-input {position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);} td .selectize-control {margin-bottom: 0;}")
    )),
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. In my actual application I have other Shiny inputs on other rows, so I used `datatable() %>% formatStyle(..., lineHeight = "32px")` to set a constant line height so there are consistent margins around each input.

Comment: @BenErnest You can use the nice `remove_button` plugin: `paste0("  $('#", id, "').selectize({plugins: ['remove_button']});")`.

Comment: Excellent, remove_button looks great!

Comment: ran into an issue with wide tables when I selectize the selectInputs with extra JavaScript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709796/datatable-with-selectinputs-resets-back-to-left-after-selection. Any chance you could take a look?