# DT Datatable with selectInputs resets back to left after selection

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, dt

I am using selectInputs in a column of a DT datatable in a Shiny app. Thanks to some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620665/vertically-center-selectinput-in-shiny-dt-datatable-when-selectize-javascript-is), I am including some JavaScript to selectize the selectInputs to keep the style and search capability of selectize. It is a wide table, so the selectInputs require scrolling horizontally to see them.

When I make a selection in any of the selectInputs the first time, everything works fine. However, when I click any of the selectInputs a second time, the page scrolls back to the left and the selectInputs are out of view. How can I keep the style and search capability I have but prevent this from happening?

**EDIT**: I also tried using shinyWidgets::pickerInput, and it does not have the scrollbar problem. However, the liveSearch feature does not work for me in a datatable. If you can solve [that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76732649/shinywidgets-pickerinput-in-dt-datatable-with-livesearch), I'll consider this question answered.

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Function to selectize one or more input ids
selectize_ids <- function(ids) {
  myStrings <- as.character(sapply(ids, function(id) {
    paste0("  $('#", id, "').selectize();")
  }))
  c(
    "function(settings){",
    myStrings,
    "}"
  )
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    div(style = "display: none;", selectInput(inputId = "dummy", label = NULL, choices = 1:2)),
    fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    df <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = paste0("text", 1:60), ncol = 20))
    colnames(df) <- paste0("column", 1:ncol(df))
    df$myselect <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
      as.character(selectInput(
        inputId = paste0("myselect_", i),
        label = NULL,
        choices = c("option1", "option2", "option3")
      ))
    })
    select_ids <- paste0("myselect_", 1:nrow(df))
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        data = df,
        escape = F,
        options = list(
          initComplete = JS(selectize_ids(select_ids))
        )
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `datatable` resets left after the second click on the `SelectInput` is that `selectize` has input fields which have `position: absolute` and `left: -10000px`. Disabling this fact can be implemented by adding CSS, e.g. for the first `SelectInput`:

```
#myselect_1-selectized {
    position: relative !important; 
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

This CSS can be generated dynamically for all your `SelectInput` inside the `datatable`

```
selectize_css <- function(ids) {
    css_list <- as.character(sapply(ids, function(id) {
        paste0("#",
               id,
               "-selectized {position: relative !important; left: 0px !important;} ")
    }))
    paste(css_list, collapse = '')
}
```

and can then be included inside the `fluidPage` by using

```
tags$style(HTML(selectize_css(select_ids)))
```

[image]

Complete minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Function to selectize one or more input ids
selectize_ids <- function(ids) {
    myStrings <- as.character(sapply(ids, function(id) {
        paste0("  $('#", id, "').selectize();")
    }))
    c("function(settings){",
      myStrings,
      "}")
}

selectize_css <- function(ids) {
    css_list <- as.character(sapply(ids, function(id) {
        paste0("#",
               id,
               "-selectized {position: relative !important; left: 0px !important;} ")
    }))
    paste(css_list, collapse = '')
}


shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tags$style(HTML(selectize_css(select_ids))),
        div(style = "display: none;", selectInput(
            inputId = "dummy",
            label = NULL,
            choices = 1:2
        )),
        fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"))
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        df <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = paste0("text", 1:60), ncol = 20))
        colnames(df) <- paste0("column", 1:ncol(df))
        df$myselect <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
            as.character(selectInput(
                inputId = paste0("myselect_", i),
                label = NULL,
                choices = c("option1", "option2", "option3")
            ))
        })
        select_ids <- paste0("myselect_", 1:nrow(df))
        output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(
                data = df,
                escape = F,
                options = list(initComplete = JS(selectize_ids(select_ids)))
            )
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Jan, this works great. I awarded the bounty to this answer because it directly solves my problem, but note another great solution on my related post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76732649/shinywidgets-pickerinput-in-dt-datatable-with-livesearch