# shinyWidgets pickerInput in DT datatable with liveSearch

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinywidgets, pickerinput

I would like to insert pickerInputs from shinyWidgets in a DT datatable in a Shiny app. However, the liveSearch option is not working for me when rendered inside a datatable. Also, when I have a separate pickerInput outside of the datatable (uncomment the pickerInput line inside fluidPage() below), the pickerInputs inside the table do not render.
I would appreciate help getting this to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    # pickerInput(inputId = "test", label = "Test", choices = c("option1", "option2")),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    df <- data.frame(
      col1 = as.character(pickerInput(
        inputId = "Picker",
        choices = c("option1", "option2", "option3", "zebra"),
        options = pickerOptions(liveSearch = T)
      ))
    )
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        data = df,
        escape = F
      ) 
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to put the **DT** table directly in the UI:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

df <- data.frame(
  col1 = as.character(pickerInput(
    inputId = "Picker",
    label = "Picker",
    choices = c("option1", "option2", "option3", "zebra"),
    options = pickerOptions(liveSearch = TRUE)
  ))
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "test", 
      label = "Test", 
      choices = c("option1", "option2"),
      options = pickerOptions(liveSearch = TRUE)
    ),
    
    datatable(
      data = df,
      escape = F
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) { }
)
```

Note that you *have to* put another picker input (such as the `"test"` one) in the UI, in order that JavaScript dependencies are loaded. If you don't want this picker input, you can hide it with some CSS (`display: none;`).

[image]

---

## Edit: in the server

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    pickerInput(inputId = "test", label = "Test", choices = c("option1", "option2")),
    DTOutput("mytable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    df <- data.frame(
      col1 = as.character(pickerInput(
        inputId = "myPicker",
        choices = c("option1", "option2", "option3", "zebra"),
        options = pickerOptions(liveSearch = TRUE)
      ))
    )
    output$mytable <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        data = df,
        escape = FALSE,
        options = list(
          initComplete = JS('function() { $("#myPicker").selectpicker(); }')
        )
      ) 
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane. This does work. However (I wasn't clear about this in my example), in my app, the data used to create the initial table come from arguments passed into a module function, and I need to use some server logic to build the table. Is there any way to build the table inside the server function and get pickerInputs to work?