# Embed Shiny widgets in a row in a DT table

Tags: r, shiny, widget, dt

I would like to embed sliderInput() widgets directly in a row in a DT table.

My problem is different to this: [Shiny widgets in DT Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034483/shiny-widgets-in-dt-table), since it uses an existing data frame (not based purely on user input).

The desired table (see picture below) shows a composite index (column "Index", column 4) that reflects the labor market situation of youth in several countries based on certain indicators (e.g. unemployment rate). Indicators are grouped into four dimensions. The (sub-)index values by dimension are shown in columns 6-9.
The four sliderInput()s in the left panel allow giving different weights to each of the four dimensions ("0" for muting it, "3" as the highest weight). Changing the sliderInput() triggers a recalculation of the aggregate index with the result of the corresponding "Weighted Index" being shown in column 5.

To show the user more intuitively to which column which sliderInput() belongs, I would like to place them directly in the table in the respective column (e.g. the sliderInput() for the dimension "Activity State" in column 6) in a row below the header. I marked the places red in the.png below. Therefore, it may be better to use a selectInput widget).

I'd be very grateful if anyone could give me a hint how to achieve this?

The header of the table was created using the package htmltools (see code below), which may complicate things.

Note that, besides the ui and sever part, the code below contains a minimal example of my data frame and a helper function that recalculates the index based on user input.

[image: Table produced by code/ mentioned in text]

**Code to reproduce problem:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#reproducible minimal data frame
YLMI <- structure(list(X = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                       name = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
                                "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Iceland"), 
                       year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), 
                       X1 = c(6.0948572, 5.1031427, 5.145143, 4.3162856, 5.9200001, 6.0751429, 5.8771429, 
                              5.0911427, 4.8957143, 6.262857), 
                       X2 = c(5.7982831, 5.1347985, 4.1193204,3.9259963, 5.9878144, 5.8885102, 5.5807657, 
                              4.5704818, 4.8845162, 5.7285347), 
                       X3 = c(5.8720002, 5.1729999, 4.1079998, 4.7049999, 5.8794999, 6.0700002, 5.3740001, 
                              5.4159999, 5.2164998, 6.3175001), 
                       X4 = c(6.0436354, 3.9714868, 6.0058327, 4.7928214, 4.636817, 6.1576967, 5.9891138, 
                              3.3220425, 3.2921035, 4.1184382), 
                       X5 = c(6.3000154, 5.7192054, 6.5671687, 3.4370663, 6.6064062, 5.8908257, 
                              6.8782973, 4.7578831, 4.3325543, 6.2499504), 
                       X6 = c(4.9257145, 5.5085716, 4.0457144, 3.737143, 2.817143, 5.0228572, 4.0057144, 
                              3.0914288, 5.3942857, 1.7485714), 
                       X7 = c(5.2685714, 5.8857141, 5.1657143, 4.4285712, 6.6914287, 3.7942855, 
                              4.8914285, 5.7142859, 5.2857141, 5.0457144), 
                       X8 = c(5.7268553, 5.3676248, 5.7317734, 5.1083288, 4.9277864, 6.2327962, 
                              6.1439047, 5.5020885, 5.9025269, 5.6717625), 
                       X9 = c(4.7919998, 5.428, 5.1039996, 4.7199998, 5.4880004, 6.2319999, 5.1399999, 
                              5.3560004, 5.4160004, 5.3560004), 
                       X10 = c(4.7384157, 3.7913544, 4.4407039, 5.8613172, 3.5934217, 5.534936, 
                               4.0672798, 4.2066154, 4.3676648, 3.6402931), 
                       X11 = c(5.7328, 5.1810961, 5.4579573, 5.5078635, 5.3274336, 5.7784905, 
                               5.5863309, 5.2231383, 5.3318233, 5.2328768), 
                       X12 = c(5.6389961, 3.9419262, 2.6277056, 4.8922715, 4.4109187, 6.3135815, 
                               5.6100388, 6.3433652, 4.5896773, 6.6938777), 
                       W1 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W2 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833,
                              0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833), 
                       W3 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W4 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W5 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W6 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W7 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W8 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W9 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W10 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W11 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W12 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       indicators = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
                       classes = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
                       index_constant = c(5.51, 4.9, 4.69, 4.78, 5.12, 5.84, 5.35, 5.02, 4.92, 5.28), 
                       ranking = c(18L, 48L, 59L, 53L, 31L, 7L, 25L, 36L, 45L, 27L)), 
                  row.names = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                  class = "data.frame")





#helper function:
# ---- Index Calculation Based on User Weights ---- #
calculate_index_w_weights <- function(w1,w2,w3,w4) {
  
  # Obtaining weights
  weights <- array(rep(1,4)) 
  
  # Creating weight matrices to re-calculate the indicator scores.
  w1_matrix <- matrix(weights[1], nrow= 10, ncol=3)
  w2_matrix <- matrix(weights[2], nrow= 10, ncol=5)
  w3_matrix <- matrix(weights[3], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  w4_matrix <- matrix(weights[4], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  
  # Unnecessary for now
  YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")]<-YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] * w1_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")]<-YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7","W8")] * w2_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]<-YLMI[,c("W9","W10")] * w3_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W11","W12")]<-YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] * w4_matrix
  
  ActivityState = YLMI[,c("X1", "X2", "X3")] * YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] #5454x3
  WorkingConditions= YLMI[,c("X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8")] * YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7", "W8")]  #5454x5
  Education= YLMI[,c("X9", "X10")] * YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]  #5454x2
  TransitionSmoothness= YLMI[,c("X11", "X12")] * YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] #5454x2
  
  c1 <- rowSums(ActivityState) #5454 x 1 sum(x1*w1....)
  c2 <- rowSums(WorkingConditions)
  c3 <- rowSums(Education)
  c4 <- rowSums(TransitionSmoothness)
  
  w1_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")])
  w2_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")])
  w3_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W9","W10")])
  w4_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W11","W12")])
  
  # weighted_index  = YLMI_Nominator / sum_weights
  ActivityState = c1 / w1_i
  WorkingConditions = c2 / w2_i
  Education = c3 / w3_i
  TransitionSmoothness = c4 / w4_i
  
  # Category weighting
  weights_category <- array(rep(0.25,4)) 
  
  # User input on weights
  w_unit <- 1 / (w1+w2+w3+w4)
  weights_category[1] <- w_unit * w1
  weights_category[2] <- w_unit * w2
  weights_category[3] <- w_unit * w3
  weights_category[4] <- w_unit * w4
  
  w1_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[1], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w2_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[2], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w3_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[3], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w4_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[4], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  
  categories <- data.frame(ActivityState, WorkingConditions, Education, TransitionSmoothness,
                           W1_C=w1_cat_matrix, W2_C=w2_cat_matrix, W3_C= w3_cat_matrix, W4_C=w4_cat_matrix)
  
  categories[is.na(categories) == TRUE] = 0
  
  # If category value is zero, then no weight assigned to that category for the index calculation.
  categories <- within(categories, W1_C[ActivityState == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W2_C[WorkingConditions == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W3_C[Education == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W4_C[TransitionSmoothness == 0] <- 0)
  
  weights_category_sum <-rowSums(categories[,c("W1_C","W2_C","W3_C","W4_C")])
  
  YLMI_Nominator1=categories[,c("ActivityState")] * categories[,c("W1_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator2=categories[,c("WorkingConditions")] * categories[,c("W2_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator3=categories[,c("Education")] * categories[,c("W3_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator4=categories[,c("TransitionSmoothness")] * categories[,c("W4_C")]
  
  YLMI_Nominator = YLMI_Nominator1 + YLMI_Nominator2 + YLMI_Nominator3 + YLMI_Nominator4
  index  = YLMI_Nominator / weights_category_sum
  
  YLMI["weighted_index"]<-index
  YLMI["ActivityState"]<-ActivityState
  YLMI["WorkingConditions"]<-WorkingConditions
  YLMI["Education"]<-Education
  YLMI["TransitionSmoothness"]<-TransitionSmoothness
  
  #creating subset for single indicator scores
  YLMI_IScores <- data.frame(
    Country = YLMI[, c("name")],
    Year = YLMI[, c("year")],
    Classes = YLMI[, c("classes")],
    Index = YLMI[, c("index_constant")],
    Weighted_Index = YLMI[, c("weighted_index")],
    ActivityState=YLMI[, c("ActivityState")],
    WorkingConditions=YLMI[, c("WorkingConditions")],
    Education=YLMI[, c("Education")],
    TransitionSmoothness=YLMI[, c("TransitionSmoothness")],
    UnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X1")],
    RelaxedUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X2")],
    NEETRate = YLMI[, c("X3")],
    TemporaryWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X4")],
    InvoluntaryPartTimeWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X5")],
    AtypicalWorkingHoursRate = YLMI[, c("X6")],
    InWorkatRiskofPovertyRate = YLMI[, c("X7")],
    VulnerableEmploymentRate =  YLMI[, c("X8")],
    FormalEducationandTrainingRate = YLMI[, c("X9")],
    SkillsMismatchRate = YLMI[, c("X10")],
    RelativeUnemploymentRatio = YLMI[, c("X11")],
    LongTermUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X12")])
  
  # Deleting rows if calculated index is NaN
  YLMI_IScores <- YLMI_IScores[!is.na(YLMI_IScores$Index), ]
  
  YLMI_IScores[is.na(YLMI_IScores) == TRUE] = "-"
  return(YLMI_IScores)
}




##server##
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #scoreboard
 
  
  #table layout for scoreboard
  sketch <- htmltools:: withTags(
    table(
      class = "display",
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = 3, "Selection", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Aggregate Index", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 4, "Sub-Index Values by Dimension", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 3, "Dimension: Activity State", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 5, "Dimension: Working Conditions", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Education", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Transition Smoothness", style = "border-right: solid 2px;")
        ),
        
        tr(
          th("Country"),
          th("Year"),
          th("Classes", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Index"),
          th("Weighted Index", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Activity State"), 
          th("Working Conditions"),
          th("Education"),
          th("Transition Smoothness", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Unemployment Rate"),
          th("Relaxed Unemployment Rate"),
          th("NEET Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Temporary Workers Rate"),
          th("Involuntary Part Time Workers Rate"),
          th("Atypical Working Hours Rate"),
          th("In Work at Risk of Poverty Rate"),
          th("Vulnerable Employment Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Formal Educationand Training Rate"),
          th("Skills Mismatch Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Relative Unemployment Ratio"),
          th("Long Term Unemployment Rate")
        ),
        
      )
    )
  )
  
  #data filtering based on user input
  
  filterData <- reactive({
    
    w1 <- input$w_1
    w2 <- input$w_2
    w3 <- input$w_3
    w4 <- input$w_4
    
    
    YLMI_IScores <- calculate_index_w_weights(w1,w2,w3,w4)
    
    rows <- (YLMI_IScores$Country %in% input$country_scb) & (YLMI_IScores$Classes %in% input$country_classes_scb)
    data <- YLMI_IScores[rows,, drop = FALSE]
    data2 <- datatable(data, rownames = FALSE, container = sketch,
                       options = list(info = TRUE, order= list(3,"dsc"), pageLength = 50,
                                      columnDefs = list(list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")))) %>%
      formatStyle(c(3,5,9,12,17,19,21), `border-right` = "solid 2px") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Index", backgroundColor = "#fdb9c4") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Weighted_Index", backgroundColor = "#f72a66") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "ActivityState", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "WorkingConditions", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Education", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "TransitionSmoothness", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatRound(columns = c(4:21), digits = 2)
    data2
    
  })
  
  output$scb_table <- DT::renderDT({
    filterData()
  })
  
  
  
}


##ui ##
 
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  #scoreboard
               sidebarPanel(
                 pickerInput(
                   inputId = "country_scb",
                   label = "Select country/countries",
                   selected = unique(sort(YLMI$name)), # Default selecting all the countries here! TODO
                   choices = unique(sort(YLMI$name)),
                   multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
                 ),
                 
                 awesomeCheckboxGroup(
                   inputId = "country_classes_scb",
                   label = "Filter countries by data availability:", 
                   choices = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),
                   selected = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),                         
                 ),
                 ######  ----- Weight Buttons ---- #####
                 # Weight Arangements 1
                 sliderInput("w_1",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Activity State:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 ),  
                 
                 # Weight Arangements 2
                 sliderInput("w_2",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Working Conditions:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 ),  
                 # Weight Arangements 3
                 sliderInput("w_3",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Education:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 ), 
                 # Weight Arangements 4
                 sliderInput("w_4",
                             label = "Select weight of Dimension Transitional Smoothness:",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 3,
                             value = 1,
                             step=1,
                             sep = ""
                 )
               ),
               mainPanel( 
                 # Show data table   
                 DT::dataTableOutput("scb_table")
                 
               )
             )
           )


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `selectInput`. We can wrap the inputs in a `div` and use the `escape = FALSE` argument - and add `Shiny.bindAll` in the `drawCallback`.

Furthermore I'm using `dataTableProxy` along with `replaceData` to update the table otherwise you'll run into the problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006107/dt-link-binding-is-lost-after-re-rendering-the-table).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
# library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

#reproducible minimal data frame
YLMI <- structure(list(X = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                       name = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", 
                                "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Iceland"), 
                       year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), 
                       X1 = c(6.0948572, 5.1031427, 5.145143, 4.3162856, 5.9200001, 6.0751429, 5.8771429, 
                              5.0911427, 4.8957143, 6.262857), 
                       X2 = c(5.7982831, 5.1347985, 4.1193204,3.9259963, 5.9878144, 5.8885102, 5.5807657, 
                              4.5704818, 4.8845162, 5.7285347), 
                       X3 = c(5.8720002, 5.1729999, 4.1079998, 4.7049999, 5.8794999, 6.0700002, 5.3740001, 
                              5.4159999, 5.2164998, 6.3175001), 
                       X4 = c(6.0436354, 3.9714868, 6.0058327, 4.7928214, 4.636817, 6.1576967, 5.9891138, 
                              3.3220425, 3.2921035, 4.1184382), 
                       X5 = c(6.3000154, 5.7192054, 6.5671687, 3.4370663, 6.6064062, 5.8908257, 
                              6.8782973, 4.7578831, 4.3325543, 6.2499504), 
                       X6 = c(4.9257145, 5.5085716, 4.0457144, 3.737143, 2.817143, 5.0228572, 4.0057144, 
                              3.0914288, 5.3942857, 1.7485714), 
                       X7 = c(5.2685714, 5.8857141, 5.1657143, 4.4285712, 6.6914287, 3.7942855, 
                              4.8914285, 5.7142859, 5.2857141, 5.0457144), 
                       X8 = c(5.7268553, 5.3676248, 5.7317734, 5.1083288, 4.9277864, 6.2327962, 
                              6.1439047, 5.5020885, 5.9025269, 5.6717625), 
                       X9 = c(4.7919998, 5.428, 5.1039996, 4.7199998, 5.4880004, 6.2319999, 5.1399999, 
                              5.3560004, 5.4160004, 5.3560004), 
                       X10 = c(4.7384157, 3.7913544, 4.4407039, 5.8613172, 3.5934217, 5.534936, 
                               4.0672798, 4.2066154, 4.3676648, 3.6402931), 
                       X11 = c(5.7328, 5.1810961, 5.4579573, 5.5078635, 5.3274336, 5.7784905, 
                               5.5863309, 5.2231383, 5.3318233, 5.2328768), 
                       X12 = c(5.6389961, 3.9419262, 2.6277056, 4.8922715, 4.4109187, 6.3135815, 
                               5.6100388, 6.3433652, 4.5896773, 6.6938777), 
                       W1 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W2 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833,
                              0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833), 
                       W3 = c(0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833, 
                              0.0833), 
                       W4 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W5 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W6 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W7 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W8 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05), 
                       W9 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W10 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W11 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       W12 = c(0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125), 
                       indicators = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
                       classes = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
                       index_constant = c(5.51, 4.9, 4.69, 4.78, 5.12, 5.84, 5.35, 5.02, 4.92, 5.28), 
                       ranking = c(18L, 48L, 59L, 53L, 31L, 7L, 25L, 36L, 45L, 27L)), 
                  row.names = c(511L, 700L, 943L, 1402L, 1429L, 1483L, 1726L, 1834L, 1861L, 2266L), 
                  class = "data.frame")





#helper function:
# ---- Index Calculation Based on User Weights ---- #
calculate_index_w_weights <- function(w1,w2,w3,w4) {
  
  # Obtaining weights
  weights <- array(rep(1,4)) 
  
  # Creating weight matrices to re-calculate the indicator scores.
  w1_matrix <- matrix(weights[1], nrow= 10, ncol=3)
  w2_matrix <- matrix(weights[2], nrow= 10, ncol=5)
  w3_matrix <- matrix(weights[3], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  w4_matrix <- matrix(weights[4], nrow= 10, ncol=2)
  
  # Unnecessary for now
  YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")]<-YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] * w1_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")]<-YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7","W8")] * w2_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]<-YLMI[,c("W9","W10")] * w3_matrix
  YLMI[,c("W11","W12")]<-YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] * w4_matrix
  
  ActivityState = YLMI[,c("X1", "X2", "X3")] * YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")] #5454x3
  WorkingConditions= YLMI[,c("X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8")] * YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6", "W7", "W8")]  #5454x5
  Education= YLMI[,c("X9", "X10")] * YLMI[,c("W9","W10")]  #5454x2
  TransitionSmoothness= YLMI[,c("X11", "X12")] * YLMI[,c("W11","W12")] #5454x2
  
  c1 <- rowSums(ActivityState) #5454 x 1 sum(x1*w1....)
  c2 <- rowSums(WorkingConditions)
  c3 <- rowSums(Education)
  c4 <- rowSums(TransitionSmoothness)
  
  w1_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W1","W2","W3")])
  w2_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W4","W5","W6","W7", "W8")])
  w3_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W9","W10")])
  w4_i <-rowSums(YLMI[,c("W11","W12")])
  
  # weighted_index  = YLMI_Nominator / sum_weights
  ActivityState = c1 / w1_i
  WorkingConditions = c2 / w2_i
  Education = c3 / w3_i
  TransitionSmoothness = c4 / w4_i
  
  # Category weighting
  weights_category <- array(rep(0.25,4)) 
  
  # User input on weights
  w_unit <- 1 / (w1+w2+w3+w4)
  weights_category[1] <- w_unit * w1
  weights_category[2] <- w_unit * w2
  weights_category[3] <- w_unit * w3
  weights_category[4] <- w_unit * w4
  
  w1_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[1], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w2_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[2], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w3_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[3], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  w4_cat_matrix <- matrix(weights_category[4], nrow= 10, ncol=1)
  
  categories <- data.frame(ActivityState, WorkingConditions, Education, TransitionSmoothness,
                           W1_C=w1_cat_matrix, W2_C=w2_cat_matrix, W3_C= w3_cat_matrix, W4_C=w4_cat_matrix)
  
  categories[is.na(categories) == TRUE] = 0
  
  # If category value is zero, then no weight assigned to that category for the index calculation.
  categories <- within(categories, W1_C[ActivityState == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W2_C[WorkingConditions == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W3_C[Education == 0] <- 0)
  categories <- within(categories, W4_C[TransitionSmoothness == 0] <- 0)
  
  weights_category_sum <-rowSums(categories[,c("W1_C","W2_C","W3_C","W4_C")])
  
  YLMI_Nominator1=categories[,c("ActivityState")] * categories[,c("W1_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator2=categories[,c("WorkingConditions")] * categories[,c("W2_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator3=categories[,c("Education")] * categories[,c("W3_C")]
  YLMI_Nominator4=categories[,c("TransitionSmoothness")] * categories[,c("W4_C")]
  
  YLMI_Nominator = YLMI_Nominator1 + YLMI_Nominator2 + YLMI_Nominator3 + YLMI_Nominator4
  index  = YLMI_Nominator / weights_category_sum
  
  YLMI["weighted_index"]<-index
  YLMI["ActivityState"]<-ActivityState
  YLMI["WorkingConditions"]<-WorkingConditions
  YLMI["Education"]<-Education
  YLMI["TransitionSmoothness"]<-TransitionSmoothness
  
  #creating subset for single indicator scores
  YLMI_IScores <- data.frame(
    Country = YLMI[, c("name")],
    Year = YLMI[, c("year")],
    Classes = YLMI[, c("classes")],
    Index = YLMI[, c("index_constant")],
    Weighted_Index = YLMI[, c("weighted_index")],
    ActivityState=YLMI[, c("ActivityState")],
    WorkingConditions=YLMI[, c("WorkingConditions")],
    Education=YLMI[, c("Education")],
    TransitionSmoothness=YLMI[, c("TransitionSmoothness")],
    UnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X1")],
    RelaxedUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X2")],
    NEETRate = YLMI[, c("X3")],
    TemporaryWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X4")],
    InvoluntaryPartTimeWorkersRate = YLMI[, c("X5")],
    AtypicalWorkingHoursRate = YLMI[, c("X6")],
    InWorkatRiskofPovertyRate = YLMI[, c("X7")],
    VulnerableEmploymentRate =  YLMI[, c("X8")],
    FormalEducationandTrainingRate = YLMI[, c("X9")],
    SkillsMismatchRate = YLMI[, c("X10")],
    RelativeUnemploymentRatio = YLMI[, c("X11")],
    LongTermUnemploymentRate = YLMI[, c("X12")])
  
  # Deleting rows if calculated index is NaN
  YLMI_IScores <- YLMI_IScores[!is.na(YLMI_IScores$Index), ]
  
  YLMI_IScores[is.na(YLMI_IScores) == TRUE] = "-"
  return(YLMI_IScores)
}

##server##
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #scoreboard
  
  #table layout for scoreboard
  sketch <- htmltools:: withTags(
    table(
      class = "display",
      thead(
        tr(
          th(colspan = 3, "Selection", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Aggregate Index", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 4, "Sub-Index Values by Dimension", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 3, "Dimension: Activity State", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 5, "Dimension: Working Conditions", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Education", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(colspan = 2, "Dimension: Transition Smoothness", style = "border-right: solid 2px;")
        ),
        
        tr(
          th("Country"),
          th("Year"),
          th("Classes", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Index"),
          th("Weighted Index", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th(div("Activity State", br(), br(), br(), selectInput("w_1",
                                                     label = "Select weight of Dimension Activity State:",
                                                     choices = 0:3,
                                                     selected = 1
          ))),
          th(div("Working Conditions", br(), br(), selectInput("w_2",
                                                   label = "Select weight of Dimension Working Conditions:",
                                                   choices = 0:3,
                                                   selected = 1
          ))),
          th(div("Education", br(), br(), br(), selectInput("w_3",
                                                label = "Select weight of Dimension Education:",
                                                choices = 0:3,
                                                selected = 1
          ))),
          th(div("Transition Smoothness", br(), br(), selectInput("w_4",
                                                      label = "Select weight of Dimension Transitional Smoothness:",
                                                      choices = 0:3,
                                                      selected = 1
          )), style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Unemployment Rate"),
          th("Relaxed Unemployment Rate"),
          th("NEET Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Temporary Workers Rate"),
          th("Involuntary Part Time Workers Rate"),
          th("Atypical Working Hours Rate"),
          th("In Work at Risk of Poverty Rate"),
          th("Vulnerable Employment Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Formal Educationand Training Rate"),
          th("Skills Mismatch Rate", style = "border-right: solid 2px;"),
          th("Relative Unemployment Ratio"),
          th("Long Term Unemployment Rate")
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
  #data filtering based on user input
  filterData <- reactive({
    
    w1 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_1), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_1))
    w2 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_2), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_2))
    w3 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_3), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_3))
    w4 <- ifelse(is.null(input$w_4), yes = 1, no = as.integer(input$w_4))
    
    
    YLMI_IScores <- calculate_index_w_weights(w1,w2,w3,w4)
    
    rows <- (YLMI_IScores$Country %in% input$country_scb) & (YLMI_IScores$Classes %in% input$country_classes_scb)
    data <- YLMI_IScores[rows,, drop = FALSE]
    data
  })
  
  # receive initial dataset only once to avoid re-rendering the table
  initData <- reactiveVal()
  observeEvent(filterData(), {
    initData(filterData())
  }, once = TRUE)
  
  output$scb_table <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(initData(), rownames = FALSE, container = sketch, escape = FALSE,
              options = list(info = TRUE, order= list(3,"dsc"), pageLength = 50, ordering = FALSE,
                             columnDefs = list(list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")),
                             preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                             drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                             )
    ) %>%
      formatStyle(c(3,5,9,12,17,19,21), `border-right` = "solid 2px") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Index", backgroundColor = "#fdb9c4") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Weighted_Index", backgroundColor = "#f72a66") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "ActivityState", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "WorkingConditions", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "Education", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatStyle(columns = "TransitionSmoothness", backgroundColor = "#fff9ee") %>%
      formatRound(columns = c(4:21), digits = 2)
  }, server = TRUE)
  
  scb_table_proxy <- dataTableProxy(outputId = "scb_table", session = session, deferUntilFlush = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(filterData(), {
    replaceData(proxy = scb_table_proxy, data = filterData(), resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE) # must repeat rownames = FALSE see ?replaceData and ?dataTableAjax
  })
  
}

##ui ##
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    #scoreboard
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "country_scb",
        label = "Select country/countries",
        selected = unique(sort(YLMI$name)), # Default selecting all the countries here! TODO
        choices = unique(sort(YLMI$name)),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      ),
      awesomeCheckboxGroup(
        inputId = "country_classes_scb",
        label = "Filter countries by data availability:", 
        choices = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),
        selected = unique(sort(YLMI$classes)),                         
      )
    ),
    mainPanel( 
      # Show data table   
      DT::dataTableOutput("scb_table")
      
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @ismirsehregal. Your answer was very helpful! Two small follow-up questions: i) do you know how I could center the select weight dropdown below a column "header" (e.g. "Activity State")? ii) Do you know if there is an easy way to hyphenate words (e.g. split long words in smaller parts).  Is the solution to split a word into two parts over two rows in the "sketch <- htmltools:: withTags( ...)" part? The aim of this would be to reduce space between all columns in the table to fit it to the browser window.. Would be cool if you had an immediate answer. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @jmk sorry I don't know how to center the dropdown choices - maybe you can put that in a separate question. Regarding the linebreak you could wrap the label in a div again and use e.g. `div("Select weight of Dimension Working Conditions:", style = "line-break: loose;")`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-break) for more information.